# Creating a form using a path argument

Tags: 7, forms

I'm writing a simple module to handle newsletter subscriptions and I want to create a form which is based on information passed in as a url argument.

Example path: /subscribe/verify/eiurhgiergierugskdfadsf

I'd like to create a form for /subscribe/verify which takes "eiurhgiergierugskdfadsf" as a parameter so that I can lookup the user by that hash value and then populate the form with their subscriber id and other information.

I can't seem to figure out how to get url arguments available in my form function though.

```
$items['subscribe/verify'] = array(
    'title' => 'Verify Email',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('subscribe_terms_form_verify'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);



function subscribe_terms_form_verify($unique_id) {
   ...
}
```

How do I safely get access to the url parameter in my form callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to introduce the argument as a 'wildcard', and pass it through to your function in the `page arguments` like so:

```
$items['subscribe/verify/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Verify Email',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('subscribe_terms_form_verify', 2),
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);
```

The [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) docs are worth read, they explain wildcards in good detail.

Your form function will have this signature:

```
function subscribe_terms_form_verify($form, &$form_state, $unique_id) {

}
```

`$form` and `$form_state` are provided as parameters to your form through `drupal_get_form()`, so the 3rd argument will contain the information passed from the URL.

Comment: Well said Clive! Nice answer as always :)

Comment: I tell you.. I have -tried- to read the wildcard docs about hook_menu(), but they are essentially TOO robust for a n00b. Until I'm able to learn the simple situations, it's hard to really understand what it is describing about the complex situations.

Comment: Thank you for this, it worked! The other examples I had found on SO all referenced 1 extra method parameter and therefore only included 1 in the page arguments array which wouldn't work for me... this worked like a charm.

Comment: Menu wildcards are just one of those things, once you know it you know it but until then it can be confusing. The number that you pass to the `page arguments` is based on the URL string itself. It breaks down by splitting the URL by the '/' character, then counting from zero until you hit the `%` character. So for the URL `subscribe/%` the index would be `1`, for `subscribe/verify/%` it's 2, for `subscribe/verify/something/%` it's 3 and so on